# Using php as an array value for strtr

Tags: php, replace

I'm trying to load a file with `PHP` inside that I want executed, and I also want to be able to replace particular words with a value of my choice.

So for example, I have 2 files, `index.php` and `test.php`

`Index.php`

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id` = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(":id",$_COOKIE[id]);
$stmt->execute();

$in = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function callback($buffer)
{
$ID = 'hesdfsdfsdy';
$arr = array(
    "{ID}" => ''.$in['id'].'',
    "{TITLE}" => 'Testttingggg'
);
  return (strtr($buffer,$arr));
}

ob_start("callback");
include 'test.php';
?>
```

Everything is working, except for the fact that `{ID}` comes out empty as it won't show `$in['id']` as the value. If I use `$ID` instead of `$in['id']` it'll show the value of `"hesdfsdfsdy"` like its meant to. So somethings not quite working with `$in`. If I use `$in['id']` inside the `test.php` it works fine. Its just that it doesn't want to work with the replacement.

`test.php`

```
<?php
echo '{TITLE} - '.$in["id"].';
?>
```

So my question is, why can't I get `$in["id"]` to work when using `{ID}`.

Thank you

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(":id",$_COOKIE[id]);` need to be `$stmt->bindValue(":id",$_COOKIE['id']);`. also i think you need to add `session_start();` on top of your each `.php` page just after `<?php`

Comment: @Anant , Thanks for replying. I've fixed these up thank you. Although i'm still experiencing the same problem

Comment: what `var_dump($in);`says? check and show us also

Comment: Where would the best place to put that be?

Comment: just after `$in = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and check what its showing on browser.

Comment: If I put it in test.php it comes out as `NULL`, if I put it in index.php, nothing appears no matter where I put it. If I put `var_dump($in['id']);` anywhere except for the function it shows up as `string(1) "1"` if I put it inside the function it shows nothing.

Comment: I just put it where you told me to, and it appears with array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" plus all the other fields I have in my users table in the database

Comment: I think you need to inherit ```$in``` variable from the parent scope. Take a look at the [Example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) from the php docs.

Comment: Yes, I think @Alexander found the reason. The array `$in` is not visible within the callback function. Inheritance should help. Alternatively you could use `global $in;` within the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `$in` is not in scope of `callback`.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = 123;

function callback($buffer)
{
    global $id;
    return strtr($buffer, ['{ID}' => $id]);
}

ob_start('callback');

echo 'Id value: {ID}';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php